# Can a sitemap.xml contain nested sitemaps from another subdomain?

Tags: seo

If the sitemap at the root domain `https://example.com/sitemap.xml` contains a reference to another sitemap on a subdomain:

```xml
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://app.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

And the sitemap at the subdomain `https://app.example.com/sitemap.xml` contains a location on the root domain:

```xml
<urlset xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/my-page</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Will Google still index `https://example.com/my-page`, despite the sitemap chain being:

```
example.com/sitemap.xml -> app.example.com/sitemap.xml -> example.com/my-page
```

In other words, will it work despite the subdomains being different?

Comment: Sitemaps have almost nothing to do with what gets indexed or how search engines rank your pages.   At best, sitemaps get Googlebot to fully crawl your site and give you extra stats in Google Search Console.   To get pages indexed and ranked, you need to make sure every page has links from other pages.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for that insight. If I still want to use sitemaps, do you also have an answer to the question given?

Comment: It's fine to use site maps. They certainly don't hurt. Just don't expect them to do miracles for your SEO. I don't know the answer to your original question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was more wondering if you have a reply to the original question.